# Jenkins : Change the name of JenkinsFile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm using **Pipeline Plugin** under Jenkins

My job is basically using a file called "**jenkinsFile**" to get the divers steps to run.

**->** My purpose is how to let the job use a different file name :

**examples:**

- myJenkinsFile
- build_JenkinsFile
- deploy_JenkinsFile
- buildSteps
- ...

Since it seems that "**JenkinsFile**" is a conventional format ,

is there any ways **to change it** if it's not verry clean ??

**Suggestions ??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the project section of the configuration page you just have to click Add > Pipeline Jenkins and then you can choose the custom name that jenkins will look for the pipeline.

[image]

If you want also a better level of customization you can also use Remote File Plugin, which allows you to put your pipeline in a repository and make it work with multiple repositories/branch (and of course you can still customize the name of the file)